# Calculate attributes from a polygon layer based on percent within another polygon layer

Tags: qgis

I have two polygon layers both in EPSG:4269 - NAD83:

1. One layer is 2020 zctas
2. The other is 2022 census blocks

The census block layer has two attributes/columns containing counts (int).

I'd like to calculate the counts in the block layer for the each zcta based on the area of the blocks within the zctas. For example, say zcta 10001 has an overlap with blocks 1, 2, 3. And the blocks have attributes like this:

| block | count1 | count2 | area in zcta 10001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | .5 |
| 2 | 40 | 80 | .4 |
| 3 | 15 | 30 | 1 |

count1 would be calculated to

10 * .5 = 5
+
40 * .4 = 16
+
15 * 1 = 15

for a total of 36
and I'd like to end up with a table like this:

| ztca | sum of count1 from blocks | sum of count2 from blocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 36 | 72 |
| 10002 | x | x |
| 10003 | x | x |

I know blocks are very granular and this can be done with MABLE or a crosswalk but I'm interested to understand the concepts using area in QGIS and applying it to less straight forward layers. Can this be done in QGIS?

Just using Join Attributes by Location with the intersect predicate I get counts that don't make a lot of sense.

Using Join Attributes by Location (Summary) with the summary: sum yields counts that don't appear to be correct. With the contains predicate, I get sums that are slightly lower than the total of summing the original blocks file. Using the intersects predicate, I get sums that are significantly higher than the total of summing the original blocks file.

Comment: Look at the Overlap Analysis tool as a start.

Comment: Thanks John. I looked at that but running it in either direction only yields the same number of features as the original input layer and there is nothing added to the overlap layer's attribute table that references the overlay layer. It seems like maybe the overlay layer is treated as a single feature. Does it need to be made multipart first?

Comment: I would run the multipart to singlepart tool first (the layers are temporary until saved) and then run the overlap analysis using it.  Another option is to do a union/intersect of your two layers, recalculating the areas and then exporting the attribute table to a spreadsheet for pivot table analysis.

Comment: A screenshot of the data would help. Have you already calculated `area in zcta 10001` column?